# how to pass value of checkboxes using ahref

Tags: html, coldfusion

I am using following code in my project

```
<cfoutput query="getOptions">

                <tr>
                <td align="center"> #optionname#</td>


                    <td align="center"> #DollarFormat(optionprice)#</td>

                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="OptionalID" value="#OptionID#"   ></td>
                </tr> 
                </cfoutput>
```

And i am passing the value to other form as follows

```
<a href="addtocart.cfm?pid=#productId#&OptionalID=#OptionalID#">
```

what should i do to pass all values of all the checkboxes that are checked.Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your page to use a form instead of passing the values via a link.

Something along the lines of:

```
<form name="myform" action="addToCart.cfm" method="post">
    <cfoutput>
        <input type="hidden name="pid" value="#productId#">
        <input type="hidden name="OptionalID" value="#OptionalID#">

            <cfloop query="getOptions">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"> #optionname#</td>
                    <td align="center"> #DollarFormat(optionprice)#</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="OptionalID" value="#OptionID#"></td>
                </tr>
            </cfloop>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart">
    </cfoutput>
</form>
```

You can pass as many values as you want now, and the checkboxes will come up as a list.

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Though you can get tricky with JavaScript, if you use an A to add to cart, you'll only be passing the values in the URL. You want to use a form instead.

```
<form name="cartForm" action="addtocart.cfm?pid=#productId#&OptionalID=#OptionalID#" method="POST">
    . . . .
</form>
```

Of course, this means you'd ordinarily use a submit button inside your form. If you're set on using a link, you can do

```
<a href="#" onClick="document.forms["cartForm"].submit();">Add to cart</a>
```

(note that I've omitted various  tags and escaping of # for simplicity)

Answer (score 0):

You need JavaScript for that.

First, have this in your page where you have the code you posted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddCheckboxValues(oLink, sName) {
    var arrCheckboxes = document.getElementsByName(sName);
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrCheckboxes.length; i++) {
        if (arrCheckboxes[i].checked) {
            values.push(arrCheckboxes[i].value);
        }
    }
    oLink.href += "&" + sName + "=" + values.join(",");
}
</script>
```

Second, add `onclick` to the link tag:

```
<a href="addtocart.cfm?pid=#productId#" onclick="AddCheckboxValues(this, 'OptionalID');">
```

That's it, now the form `addtocart.cfm` will get query string values of the checkboxes ticked by the user.